# making a stream of increasing positive numbers scale and count down and up

Tags: math, theory

I have a master variable generating numbers from 0 to 1000000 in sequence

I would like the first 0 to 200000 captured by a child variable that holds 0  counting up to 100000 (in sync with the master variable, and from the master's 100001 to 200000 , counts back down from 99999 to 0 backwards

my language is ksp ( c friendly ) and counting up looks like this

```
on init
      declare $master (0,1000000)  {**create master with it's range**)
      declare $child (0,100000)    {**create child with it's range**}
end on 

on ui_control ($master)     {**when the master generates numbers**}
    if (in_range($master,0,100000))
        $child := $master   {**assign master's value to child when in range**}
    end if
    if (in_range($master,100001,200000))
        $child := ???         {**count backwards from 99999 to 0 please**}
    end if
end on
```

so my question is what code do I write to make the child treat 100001 to 200000 as 99999 to 0 counting backwards as the master generates 100001 to 200000? i have an abs operator available , i could use negative numbers without any issues, is that what I need to use somehow? 
 i've not had to solve this type of issue before..

as you probably realise, there will be other children for the rest of the values but if i can get this one right they will all follow the same pattern.

Comment: c = 200000-m, and please learn to use punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

ok I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question here. If you are a ksp user and you come across this, here is an answer you can load up and watch it work.

```
on init
    declare $new_value
    declare ui_slider $master (0,1000000)
    message("")
end on

on ui_control ($master)
   $new_value := abs ($master - 1000000)

    message ($master & "  :::: " & $new_value)
end on
```